# Xcode shows warning after adding App Groups (Add the "App Groups" entitlement to your App ID)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-app-group

After I added an App Group in Xcode it shows a warning:

> Add the "App Groups" entitlement to your App ID
>   Add the "App Groups containers" entitlement to your App ID

Before the warning there was a loading spinner like this:

[image: Adding the "App Groups" entitlement to your App ID...]

after it finished the loading I got the following warnings:

[image: remaining warnings]

What can I do to correct the two wrong steps? If I'm right it is already added to my App ID.

Comment: App Groups" entitlement must be unique…

Comment: thanks for the tip but it's not the problem. the App Groups entitlement is unique

Comment: I just clicked "Fix Issues" and the exclamation marks turned into ✓

Comment: @OhadSchneider that doesn't worked in my situation but it was a year ago.

Comment: Nah, don't close it. It will be useful for others.

Comment: This seems like a legitimate question to me, for example, I'm here because I downloaded a sample app codebase, and you have to reset the signing to side-load with an extension.

Comment: I do not think this is off-topic at all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I faced the same issue, and in my case my apple id did not have the permission to add the "App Group".

If your account's type is "Member", not "Agent", then you need your Agent/Admin who has the main development account to add the "App Group" for you.

Comment: I'm not sure if it was the answer but there was something wrong with the provisioning file. After I checked it and clicked there on a fix button everything worked well. Thanks :)

Comment: I have also updated my App Id with "App Groups" but still facing same issue. Could you please tell me what should I do exactly?

Comment: Please note that now you are allowed to develop on Apple devices without Developer membership, but this does not include App Groups feature. So if you are not enrolled, this error will occur.

Comment: In my case I was facing the same error, I resolved  it by providing app groups to app id before setting up app groups in Xcode

Answer (score 9):

For me, what worked was I had to changed the `Bundle Identifier` because I was working with a project template I had downloaded from the internet.

You can change that in:

```
Project Navigator -> Target -> <Your target> -> General tab
```

[image: bundle identifier]

After that, I checked the `App Groups` and the warnings had gone

[image: result]

Comment: FWIW This is the only thing that worked for me. My bundle Identifiers were in there and fine, but Xcode was still marking it as not found. Furthermore, when I checked the checkbox for my app group, it would DUPLICATE the value, e.g. I'd have TWO checkboxes checked, but still the same error. Changing the bundle ID (and then changing it back) seemed to have reset things inside XCode. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can try this steps:

1. Find your App Id and make sure your App Group state is Enabled.
2. Use your App Id to create Provisioning Profiles and download to your computer then double click it
3. Check Xcode's Identity to make sure your team is the right one. If you have problems, click fix issue

Comment: This is essentially what fixed the issue for me. The important step, I think, being _re-downloading_ the Provisioning Profiles _after_ I set the App Group.

Comment: Life saver......

Answer (score 5):

For me, what worked was having the phone attached. Once I attached it, Xcode was able to finish the process and the two red check mark problems were resolved.

Comment: it seems that xcode is good in not telling the exact problem.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was not having the App Groups set up correctly on all my App IDs on the Developer Portal. Therefor the App Groups in the app didn't work correctly.

Answer (score -2):

You can just go to here and press fix issue to add your app ID, Bundle identifier and code signing first to your Developer ID[image]

Comment: it's already a long time ago I had this issue. I tried this button but it ends in excatly the same warning. So the button was useless at the moment I got that error.